# How to prove this inequality using the definite integral definition?

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on the below problem and would appreciate an explanation of the proof. My confusion is as follows: if we look at the integral of 1/x (log x), we would then plug in 2 for x; *however, the Riemann sum is not dependent upon x, so any x would satisfy the inequality. The definition of the definite integral is that this is the unique value, however it is not unique if the inequality can be satisfied with any value.* What is the basis for saying 2 is the unique value?

thanks
[image]

Comment: Look at the integral of $f=\frac{1}{x}$ from $n$ to $2n$.

Comment: This reminds me of the proof of the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence#Proof). It might be useful to check it out.

Comment: "*a candidate for f is 0 as the integral of this is any constant*" $\;-\;$ Quite obviously not true, though it's anybody's guess what else you really meant to say. Anyway, the choice of the function depends on the form of the two sums, because you want those to somehow become Riemann sums for the function.

Comment: In the region $~x \in [1,2],~$ draw the graph of $~y = (1/x), ~$ which is a **strictly decreasing** function.  Then, divide this region into $~n~$ equally spaced sections, and then construct two sets of rectangles:  the tall rectangles, each of whose heights are where the LHS of the rectangles intersect the $~y = (1/x)~$ graph, and the short rectangles, each of  whose heights are where the RHS of the rectangles intersect the $~y = (1/x) ~$ graph. ...see next comment

Comment: You will then be able to **tell graphically** that the combined area of the tall rectangles is greater than the area under the curve, **because** the tall rectangles completely cover the region under the curve.  Similarly, the combined area of the short rectangles is less than the area under the curve, **because** the short rectangles are completely covered by the region under the curve.

Comment: @God Please do not change the question, especially after answers have been posted. The original question was about finding/choosing a candidate function, now you made it about something else, though it's not clear what exactly. "*any x would satisfy*" $\;-\;$ Which $\,x\,$? If you change the function, or the interval, or the partition, then that changes the Riemann sums. You must choose all of them in such a way as to match the inequality you want to prove.

Comment: @dxiv thank you; can you provide an example of the original values we choose such that we can have this inequality proven for log2, as oppose to any generic value of x in logx?

Comment: @God That's precisely what the posted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4669869/291201) does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $$f(x) = \frac 1{1+x} \text{ on } I=[0,1]$$
Use the specific equidistant partition
$$x_k = \frac kn \text{ for } k=0,\ldots , n$$
Now consider the lower sum $L$ and the upper sum U wrt. this partition:
$$L = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1+\frac kn}\cdot \frac 1n$$
$$U = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac1{1+\frac kn} \cdot \frac 1n$$
From a standard definition of the Riemann-integral using lower and upper sums we know that
$$L\leq \int_0^1\frac1{1+x}\;dx = \ln 2 \leq U$$

Comment: thank you! I am unsure of how we can plug in 1 for x to get ln2 from the integral ln(|x+1|). My understanding was that the value between these sums was supposed to be unique, and there wasn't an infinite amount of them. Your argument seems to be that this holds for any x, so we can plug in 1; did I understand that correctly? Was my understanding of the value of the integral at x being unique wrong?

Comment: I recommend you to revise the definition of the Riemann integral. $L$ and $U$ represent specific estimates for the given integral.